# xml2js read from url

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js

So I have NodeJS and installed the module xml2js. In the tutorial we have an example taking an xml file from directory and convert it with `JSON.stringify()` as in the example. Now is there a possibility instead of calling the local xml file (foo.xml), to call a url of XML service for ex: [www.wunderground.com/city.ect/$data=xml](http://www.wunderground.com/city.ect/%24data=xml)

```
var parser = new xml2js.Parser(); 
parser.addListener('end', function(result) {
    var res = JSON.stringify(result);   
        console.log('converted'); 
}); 
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/foo.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data); 
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can use online resource. Just fetch the XML before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an http request instead of reading a file. Something like this, I think:

```
http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    parser.parseString(chunk); 
  });
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback